# how to use background image for texture in openGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

i want to use background image with texture but texture get images with power of 2 so i made image size (800x480 to 512x512).

but now it is showing image with some blank space.

how can i show image on entire screen. and also want  to horizontally scrollable .

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is on Android, that means you don't have `glDrawPixels`, so the only way you could be "showing" an image would be to render a textured quad. So just make the quad whatever size you need.

You can also draw multiple textures, just by drawing one texture to one location, then drawing another texture to another location.

Comment: can you please give any example or link

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right texture coordinates when rendering your background. You need to compute the texture coordinates so that you are having an offset for the axis perpendicular to the black borders.

I guess you resized your 800x480 image so that it fits in 512x512 pixels, making you end up with the actual background image (inside the 512x512 texture) being 512x307?

This would mean that your u texture coordinate offset would need to be (512.0 - 307.0) / 2.0 / 512.0 ~ 0.2, so your texture coordinates would need to be (0.0,0.0), (0.0,0.2), (1.0,0.2), (1.0,0.0).